# To eliminate gray stripes when taking photos from computer displays using Android SDK

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

Maybe a comparison of pictures best illustrate the problem.

This is the original picture:

[image: Original Picture]

Using Android SDK, I managed to take this photo from my Android phone:

[image: Photo get from Android device]

You may see that, there are lots of gray strips on the photo.

Although the main shapes are there, for I'm processing these photos on an image recognition project, these gray stripe completely ruined the results.

It (Edit: does not ) seems that the built-in photo app would automatically eliminate them, but I don't know how to do it manually in my app. Seems that this is caused by display having a different refresh rate.

Comment: Why would you take a photo of a computer screen, rather than a screenshot?  You can do image recognition just as well (even better) on a static screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, actually my project do fairly well on static screenshots. But since my project is oriented on recognizing these photos I have to face this problem... :(

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is happening because cameras have a small advantage over the human eye when taking the photo.

The refresh rate for most displays is 50Hz or 60Hz, which is too fast for our eyes to notice.

However, a camera sensor takes the image much faster than the human eye, and can see the scan lines created by the refreshing of the image on the display. You can work around this by using a longer exposure time, closer to the human eyes' speed, but you may not be able to control that on most Android devices.

I suggest you use your operating system's inbuilt screenshot utility instead.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this phenomenon! Actually I know that using inbuilt screenshot is well... But my project is focused on recognizing photos taken from Android devices, and because showing test pictures on screen is the easiest way to test this program, that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: You'd have better results taking a screenshot on the computer, and then sending it over USB/network/Bluetooth to the device